# English possessive in Mathematics

Tags: article-writing

As a non-native English speaker, I wonder what is the correct way to use the English possessive, also known as Saxon genitive, when dealing with mathematical objects.

It seems to me that there is not an agreement about that, some examples:

[Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)

[Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)

[Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)

[Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)

[Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function)

but also...

[Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument)

[Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/.../Euler's_totient_function)

[Ramanujan's sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan's_sum)

[Kloosterman's sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KloostermansSum.html)

[D'Alembert's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'Alembert's_formula)

Regarding theorems I think the correct way is:

"AUTHORNAME's theorem"

"FIRSTAUTHORNAME-SECONDAUTHORNAME theorem" (no 's)

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Languages are full of exceptions. (Yours?)  I look up the thing in  wiki if I want to get the (by definition) correct version

Comment: @zoli I am Italian. Of course languages are full of exceptions and I would not be surprised if both "Ramanujan's sum" and "Ramanujan sum" were correct form. However, I thought it is better to ask this question instead of looking wikipedia anytime.

Comment: You are getting up votes but not answers :  )  (I am Hungarian; the whole Hun is an exception.)

Comment: Here went mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to "Writing Mathematical Papers in English" by Jerzy Trzeciak
the following are correct:

Minkowski's inequality

the Minkowski inequality.

For theorems he suggests the following two forms:

Fefferman and Stein's famous theorem

the famous Fefferman-Stein theorem.